# EmptyDataTemplate and EmptyDataText not working in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, emptydatatext

I can't seem to get either `EmptyDataTemplate` or `EmptyDataText` of a `GridView` to work.

I'm fetching the `GridView` contents in de codebehind and attaching them with using `DataBind()`. I've tried having them as `null` and as an empty `List`, and in both cases the text I put into `EmptyDataTemplate` or `EmptyDataText` is not displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** (Code snippet)

This is my GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" EmptyDataText="EMPTY">
</asp:GridView>
```

And I've tried these two for binding the data:

```
grid.DataSource = new List<object>();
grid.DataBind();

grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is caused by using the so-called [CSS-Friendly Control Adapters](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/). With them enabled (and they seem to be enabled by default), `EmptyDataTemplate` and `EmptyDataText` don't work as expected.

To disable the adapters, go to the `App_Browsers` folder, and in the `CSSFriendlyAdapters.browser` file, comment out the following section (or the section related to the control you're using):

```
<adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.GridViewAdapter" />
```

The big problem is the styles will go away.

Comment: hi Farinha, I added related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856890/gridview-using-css-friendly-control-adapters-removes-emptydatatemplate-and-empt - hopefully there is an alternative solution that would allow keep the styles

Comment: Thanks, that at least explains things.

Comment: Thank you man, although you didn't help me directly, you saved me a lot of time, giving me a clue of the problem was tackling.. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar problem and noticed I had logic around my DataBind to ignore the databinding method if my datasource was empty.

Answer (score 2):

The `EmptyDataTemplate` will override any `EmptyDataText`, so it could be that you've defined the template incorrectly somehow, which is keeping you from seeing the `EmptyDataText`.

If you're binding an empty list to the GridView, it should display the `EmptyDataText`, so long as you don't have a conflicting `EmptyDataTemplate`, e.g.

```
<%-- GridTest.ascx --%>
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Data!" />

// GridTest.ascx.cs
Grid.DataSource = new List<object>();
Grid.DataBind();
```

Are you doing something different than this?

Comment: That's what I have (edited the question with code snippets). And instead of the GridView I just get blank. No sign of the EmptyDataText.

Comment: @Farinha When you bind a list with some contents, the GridView renders?  I'm wondering if maybe your data-binding code isn't even running...

Comment: Yes, it renders OK when there's data in it.

Answer (score 1):

Can User Empty Data Template.....

```
    <Columns>
             ............
             ............
             ............
    <Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmptyTxt" runat="server" Text="No Data"></asp:Label>
      </EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

And don't do what I did - The GridView ForeColor property wasn't set and it defaults to white which was also my BackColor property!